# Summary statistics conditional on three separate columns

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a dataset consisting of n observations with three validation columns, signalling whether they can be included in an analysis. I'd like to summarize the dataset for each of the filter columns, by summing each of the variables.

I'm having great difficulties doing so with the reshape package, the sample dataset is as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame (
  ID = c(1:20),
  Var1 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.5,1,0),
  Var2 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.5,1,0),
  Var3 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.5,1,0),
  Filter1 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.5,TRUE,FALSE),
  Filter2 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.4,TRUE,FALSE),
  Filter3 = ifelse(runif(20, min = 0, max = 1) > 0.3,TRUE,FALSE)
)
```

This returns the following dataset:

```
   ID Var1 Var2 Var3 Filter1 Filter2   Filter3
1   1    1    0    1   FALSE    TRUE      TRUE
2   2    1    1    1   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
3   3    1    1    1    TRUE   FALSE      TRUE
4   4    1    0    0    TRUE    TRUE      TRUE
5   5    1    0    0   FALSE   FALSE      TRUE
6   6    1    1    1   FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
7   7    1    0    1   FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
8   8    0    1    1   FALSE    TRUE      TRUE
9   9    0    0    0   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
10 10    1    0    1   FALSE    TRUE      TRUE
11 11    1    0    0    TRUE    TRUE     FALSE
12 12    0    1    1   FALSE   FALSE      TRUE
13 13    0    0    0    TRUE    TRUE      TRUE
14 14    0    1    1   FALSE    TRUE     FALSE
15 15    0    0    0   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
16 16    1    1    0    TRUE   FALSE      TRUE
17 17    0    1    0    TRUE   FALSE     FALSE
18 18    1    1    0   FALSE   FALSE      TRUE
19 19    1    0    0   FALSE   FALSE      TRUE
20 20    0    1    0    TRUE    TRUE      TRUE
```

For each of the filters, I want to summarize the sums of each variable like so:

```
  Filter      Variable True False
1 Filter1     Var1     2    1
2             Var2     3    0
3             Var3     1    1
4 Filter2     Var1     1    2
5             Var2     2    1
6             Var3     1    1
7 Filter3     Var1     1    2
8             Var2     1    2
9             Var3     0    2
```

Thank you for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: You don't need all this `ifelse(runif(...))` business. Look up `?sample`

Comment: I don't understand the desired logic.  I count 8 entries where `Var1==1` and `Filter1==FALSE`, and 4 entries where `Var1==1` and `Filter1==TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

You can be even more succinct by using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- data.frame (
  ID = c(1:20),
  Var1 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE),
  Var2 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE),
  Var3 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE),
  Filter1 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE) %>% as.logical,
  Filter2 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.6,0.4)) %>% as.logical,
  Filter3 = sample(0:1,20,replace = TRUE,prob = c(0.7,0.3)) %>% as.logical
  )

dat %>%
  gather(Filter, FilterTF, Filter1:Filter3) %>%
  gather(Variable, Value, Var1:Var3) %>%
  group_by(Filter, FilterTF, Variable) %>%
  summarize(Sum = sum(Value)) %>%
  spread(FilterTF, Sum, fill = 0)

## Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
## 
##    Filter Variable FALSE TRUE
## 1 Filter1     Var1     5    8
## 2 Filter1     Var2     4    8
## 3 Filter1     Var3     4    5
## 4 Filter2     Var1     5    8
## 5 Filter2     Var2     5    7
## 6 Filter2     Var3     5    4
## 7 Filter3     Var1     8    5
## 8 Filter3     Var2     8    4
## 9 Filter3     Var3     6    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to answer my own question with some additional research ;-) Doh.

In order to create a new row for each filter column:

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
Long <- melt(dat, id=c(1:4))
Long <- rename(Long,c("variable"="Filter","value"="FilterTF"))
```

Then I remelted the data to include the TRUE / FALSE component:

```
Longer <- melt(Long,id=c("ID","Filter","FilterTF"))
```

A ddply took care of the summary statistics:

```
Stats <- ddply(Longer,.(Filter,FilterTF,variable), summarise, 
                   Sum = sum(value))
```

Now I casted it utilizing reshape2 to obtain the required format:

```
dcast(Stats, Filter+variable~FilterTF, value=Sum)


   Filter variable FALSE TRUE
1 Filter1     Var1     2    1
2 Filter1     Var2     3    0
3 Filter1     Var3     1    1
4 Filter2     Var1     1    2
5 Filter2     Var2     2    1
6 Filter2     Var3     1    1
7 Filter3     Var1     1    2
8 Filter3     Var2     1    2
9 Filter3     Var3     0    2
```